# Compiling Apache Thrift Service in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, thrift

I'm trying to build a thrift service on my windows machine. Im using cygwin and Netbeans IDE. I've downloaded Thrift and built it trough cygwin and was able to successfully get Thrift to generate the server code for me, shown below.

```
#include "Feed.h"
#include <protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h>
#include <server/TSimpleServer.h>
#include <transport/TServerSocket.h>
#include <transport/TBufferTransports.h>

using namespace ::apache::thrift;
using namespace ::apache::thrift::protocol;
using namespace ::apache::thrift::transport;
using namespace ::apache::thrift::server;

using boost::shared_ptr;

using namespace feed;

class FeedHandler : virtual public FeedIf {
 public:
  FeedHandler() {
    // Your initialization goes here
  }

  void ping() {
    // Your implementation goes here
    printf("ping\n");
  }

  void search_text(search_resultset& _return, const std::string& query, const int32_t offset, const int32_t per_page) {
    // Your implementation goes here
    printf("search_text\n");
  }

  void search_prox_web(search_resultset& _return, const double lat, const double lon, const int32_t offset, const int32_t distance) {
    // Your implementation goes here
    printf("search_prox_web\n");
  }

  void search_prox_mob(search_resultset& _return, const double lat, const double lon, const int32_t offset, const int32_t distance) {
    // Your implementation goes here
    printf("search_prox_mob\n");
  }

  int32_t add_event(const std::string& name) {
    // Your implementation goes here
    printf("add_event\n");
  }

  int32_t associate_venue_with_event(const int32_t event_id, const int32_t venue_id, const int32_t usr_loc_id) {
    // Your implementation goes here
    printf("associate_venue_with_event\n");
  }

  int32_t save_usr_loc(const std::string& address) {
    // Your implementation goes here
    printf("save_usr_loc\n");
  }

};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int port = 9090;
  shared_ptr<FeedHandler> handler(new FeedHandler());
  shared_ptr<TProcessor> processor(new FeedProcessor(handler));
  shared_ptr<TServerTransport> serverTransport(new TServerSocket(port));
  shared_ptr<TTransportFactory> transportFactory(new TBufferedTransportFactory());
  shared_ptr<TProtocolFactory> protocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocolFactory());

  TSimpleServer server(processor, serverTransport, transportFactory, protocolFactory);
  server.serve();
  return 0;
}
```

Then I built the libraries so I could compile and link my implementation. The libraries built successfully, however when I try to compile I get the following error:

```
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o: In function `FeedProcessor': 
/cygdrive/c/Feed Service/Feed.h:930: undefined reference to `vtable for feed::FeedProcessor'
/cygdrive/c/Feed Service/Feed.h:930: undefined reference to `vtable for feed::FeedProcessor'
/cygdrive/c/Feed Service/Feed.h:931: undefined reference to `feed::FeedProcessor::process_ping(int, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, void*)'
/cygdrive/c/Feed Service/Feed.h:932: undefined reference to `feed::FeedProcessor::process_search_text(int, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, void*)'
/cygdrive/c/Feed Service/Feed.h:933: undefined reference to `feed::FeedProcessor::process_search_prox_web(int, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, void*)'
/cygdrive/c/Feed Service/Feed.h:934: undefined reference to `feed::FeedProcessor::process_search_prox_mob(int, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, void*)'
/cygdrive/c/Feed Service/Feed.h:935: undefined reference to `feed::FeedProcessor::process_add_event(int, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, void*)'
/cygdrive/c/Feed Service/Feed.h:936: undefined reference to `feed::FeedProcessor::process_associate_venue_with_event(int, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, void*)'
/cygdrive/c/Feed Service/Feed.h:937: undefined reference to `feed::FeedProcessor::process_save_usr_loc(int, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, void*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/feed_service.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 3s)
```

I thought these were all linker errors, so I did some googling and found a potential solution to add the following lines to the makefile:

```
THRIFT_O=C:/cygwin/home/thrift/lib/cpp
    LTHRIFT=$(THRIFT_O)/Thrift.o $(THRIFT_O)/TSocket.o $(THRIFT_O)/TSimpleServer.o $(THRIFT_O)/TBufferTransports.o $(THRIFT_O)/TSimpleServer.o $(THRIFT_O)/TBinaryProtocol.o
```

and then link with $(LTHRIFT) rather than -lthrift. However the file TBinaryProtocol.o doesn't seem to exist on my system. I tried re-building the libraries from source twice, and the file still isn't made.

First of all, is adding these lines to my makefile the correct solution to my initial problem? Secondly, is the absence of TBinaryProtocol.o a major problem, or is it not created for a reason? If I do need it, is there a way I can make it individually or download it from somewhere?

**Edit:** All of the include files are auto-generated by the Thrift compiler. I tried to include Feed.h here, but it is too big and goes over the character limit, so I included the portion that is referenced in the errors.

```
class FeedProcessor : virtual public ::apache::thrift::TProcessor {
 protected:
  boost::shared_ptr<FeedIf> iface_;
  virtual bool process_fn(::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* iprot, ::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* oprot, std::string& fname, int32_t seqid, void* callContext);
 private:
  std::map<std::string, void (FeedProcessor::*)(int32_t, ::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, ::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, void*)> processMap_;
  void process_ping(int32_t seqid, ::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* iprot, ::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* oprot, void* callContext);
  void process_search_text(int32_t seqid, ::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* iprot, ::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* oprot, void* callContext);
  void process_search_prox_web(int32_t seqid, ::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* iprot, ::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* oprot, void* callContext);
  void process_search_prox_mob(int32_t seqid, ::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* iprot, ::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* oprot, void* callContext);
  void process_add_event(int32_t seqid, ::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* iprot, ::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* oprot, void* callContext);
  void process_associate_venue_with_event(int32_t seqid, ::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* iprot, ::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* oprot, void* callContext);
  void process_save_usr_loc(int32_t seqid, ::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* iprot, ::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* oprot, void* callContext);
 public:
  FeedProcessor(boost::shared_ptr<FeedIf> iface) :
    iface_(iface) {
    processMap_["ping"] = &FeedProcessor::process_ping;
    processMap_["search_text"] = &FeedProcessor::process_search_text;
    processMap_["search_prox_web"] = &FeedProcessor::process_search_prox_web;
    processMap_["search_prox_mob"] = &FeedProcessor::process_search_prox_mob;
    processMap_["add_event"] = &FeedProcessor::process_add_event;
    processMap_["associate_venue_with_event"] = &FeedProcessor::process_associate_venue_with_event;
    processMap_["save_usr_loc"] = &FeedProcessor::process_save_usr_loc;
  }

  virtual bool process(boost::shared_ptr< ::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol> piprot, boost::shared_ptr< ::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol> poprot, void* callContext);
  virtual ~FeedProcessor() {}
};
```

Any help would be appreciated, I am very stuck on this.

Comment: What about Feed Service/Feed.h? Linker error complains about it. Can you post it(Feed.h) here?

Comment: Feed.h is auto-generated by the Thrift compiler itself, but I will post it above.

Comment: I was not working with thrift, but I work with other system that generate C++ code. And the messages that show linker is rather common for the first attempt to use them. In general people forget to include one of "generated" file to Makefile. But without Fred.h and Makefile not clear exactly what is going on.

Comment: Well, congratulations on having made it this far... last time I checked, the Thrift libraries weren't supported on Windows at all.

Comment: @user1034749: Feed.h pasted here: http://pastebin.com/bUii99FW I'll post the makefile when I get to the computer its on.

Kerrek SB: Thanks. Its been a pain-in-the-you-know-what to get this far.

Comment: So according to Feed.h feed::FeedProcessor::process_ping and other only defined, but not implemented. But in costructor of FeedProcessor there is reference to FeedProcessor::process_ping. I suspect, that there is implementation of FeedProcessor::process_ping and other in generated file. Can you also paste your Makefile?

Comment: @user1034749: My makefile is auto-generated by netbeans and is separated into many files. I pasted some of them here starting with the main Makefile: http://pastebin.com/sPZeHAda If a part is missing which you need I will add it.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness:

(1) **On Windows, there is no need to build the Thrift Compiler EXE** on your own, there is a (small) installer [to be downloaded here](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/thrift/0.9.3/thrift-0.9.3.exe).

(2) If you still want or need to build the Thrift Compiler Binaries, you still don't need to fire up Cygwin: More recent versions of Apache Thrift offer a nice [Visual Studio solution](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=tree;f=compiler/cpp;hb=HEAD) which only require [Win flex-bison](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/) as dependency. Works like a charm.

Comment: https://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/windows  according to that, that's not true, note the bit that says: "Most of the language packages must be built and installed manually using build tools better suited to those languages."

Comment: And the same page also has a section [Prebuilt Thrift Compiler](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/windows#prebuilt-thrift-compiler). What does that section say? Note that Thrift Compiler and language packages are two entirely different things.

Comment: the question was about compiling a service which requires both the compiler and the library. That's all I was getting at.

Comment: That's why I wrote "*Just for the sake of completeness*" in the first sentence.